# df.show() in PySpark returns "UnauthorizedException: User my_user has no SELECT permission on <table system.size_estimates> or any of its parents"

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to read records from Cassandra table

this code works fine:

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "my_host") \
    .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042") \
    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "my_user") \
    .option("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "my_pass") \
    .option("keyspace", "my_keyspace") \
    .option("table", "my_table") \
    .load()
```

but when i try to show records

```
df.show(3)
```

i get this exception

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.UnauthorizedException: User my_user has no SELECT permission on <table system.size_estimates> or any of its parents
```

The point is i have all permissions to my_keyspace only.

But i successfully connect with cqlsh to same cassandra host:port with same user/pass and do whatever in my_keyspace.

Please advice what's wrong with spark code and how to act in such situation?

Answer (score 2):

The Spark Cassandra connector estimates the size of the Cassandra tables using the values stored in `system.size_estimates`. The connector needs an estimate of the table size in order to calculate the number of Spark partitions. See [my answer in this post](https://community.datastax.com/questions/11500/) for details.

If you've [enabled the authorizer in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigInternalAuth.html), authenticated users/roles are automatically given read access to some system tables:

```
system_schema.keyspaces
system_schema.columns
system_schema.tables
system.local
system.peers
```

But you will need [to explicitly authorize your Spark user](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlGrant.html) so it can access the `size_estimates` table with:

```
GRANT SELECT ON system.size_estimates TO spark_role
```

Note that the role only needs read access (`SELECT` permission) to the table. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant read access to `system.size_estimation` for that user

Comment: why don't i need to be granted so if i read the table with cqlsh?

Comment: it's used by SCC to estimate number of Cassandra partitions per Spark partition